# R-Programming: Error in seq.default(1, data_length) : 'to' must be of length 1

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to calculate group standardized values of the data variables using the following function.

```
groupStandardise <- function(variables, groupvariable)
{
 # find out how many variables we have
 variables <- as.data.frame(variables)
 numvariables <- length(variables)
 # find the variable names
 variablenames <- colnames(variables)
 # calculate the group-standardised version of each variable
 for (i in 1:numvariables)
 {
    variablei <- variables[[i]]
    variablei_name <- variablenames[[i]]
    variablei_Vw <- calcWithinGroupsVariance(variablei, groupvariable)
    variablei_mean <- mean(variablei)
    variablei_new <- (variablei - variablei_mean)/(sqrt(variablei_Vw))
    data_length <- nrow(variablei)
    if (i == 1) { variables_new<-data.frame(row.names=seq(1,data_length))}
    variables_new[`variablei_name`] <- variablei_new
 }
 return(variables_new)
 }
```

While calling the function as

```
groupstandardisedconcentrations <- groupStandardise(data[,2:14], data[,1])
```

I am getting this error

> Error in seq.default(1,data_length) : 'to' must be of length 1

output of str(data) is below (v1 is the group variable):

```
'data.frame':   45 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ V1 : int  2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 ...
 $ V2 : num  1.3243 -2.4546 0.1352 0.0676 -1.1901 ...
 $ V3 : num  0.913 -2.644 0.663 1.217 -0.409 ...
 $ V4 : num  -1.863 1.965 -0.698 -0.945 0.617 ...
 $ V5 : num  -0.574 1.031 -0.308 -0.574 0.354 ...
 $ V6 : num  -0.8963 2.5702 0.0736 -1.3671 0.9045 ...
```

Any suggestion to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

this `data_length <- nrow(variablei)`  outputs a `NULL` if the object is a one dimensional vector, and then when you do this `variables_new<-data.frame(row.names=seq(1,data_length))` you are asking `R` to give you the sequence from `1` to `NULL` hence the error.

you can replicate the error by `seq(1,NULL)`

depending on your goals (you must check if the your program fits your purpose by yourself )
you can add a condition so the error doesn't occur.

you can change 
`if (i == 1)` to `if (i == 1 & !is.null(data_length))`

Comment: I see..any solution to this?

Comment: Somehow it is not returning the variables_new, showing "object variables_new not found"